# Can a program be written to solve a puzzle whose solution is not known to the programmer without brute force methods?

Tags: group-theory, computational-complexity, game-theory

Just for fun, I've written a puzzle program to see if I can solve it.
A good analogy would be Rubik's cube.

I have deliberately not tried to solve it myself, but know that it can be solved - simply by reversing shuffling operations ( as per Rubik's cube)

What I'd like to know is : Can a program be written that will solve the puzzle without using brute-force?

---

**Given that the solving program knows the following:**

- the solved state of the puzzle
- the current state of the puzzle at any time
- all actions available to the solver to change the puzzle sate

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to answer such vague question. Please state precisely what kind of problem you are trying to solve and we will help you.

Comment: Depending on the puzzle, it may be easy, hard or impossible to write a program to solve it.   Can **you**  write such a program?  Given that the only thing we know about you is that you asked this question, I suspect the answer is "no".

Comment: So you're asking if it's possible to write a program to solve a puzzle without brute force / trial and error, and without knowing a solution / algorithm ahead of time? That doesn't exactly leave you with any alternatives.

Comment: @ArukaJ: Under *some* circumstances, the states might admit of some obvious metric, for which the solved state has a unique extremum and on which the actions have some obvious impact.  It might then be possible to engineer a solution that is much better than exhaustive tree search.  Without knowing anything beyond what's given, as Robert Israel indicates, we can't say much more than that.

Comment: @BrianTung If such metrics / impacts are "obvious" then I would consider this as being comparable to "knowing the solution." If it's so obvious that only one solution really exists because brute force doesn't allow any other options, then I am not sure we can even call it a puzzle.

Comment: @ArukaJ: Well, perhaps obvious is too extreme a word.

Comment: Do you happen to have any ideas / examples in mind of these circumstances you mention?

Answer (score 0):

For exemple there are many Sudoku solvers that uses various AI-techniques to solve a grid in a few millseconds while a brute-force solution would take the age of the universe or more !

On the other hand there are also some ($NP$-)hard problems that can be proven to have no "clever" solution besides brute-force (Unless $P = NP$ but this is getting a bit technical). For exemple, if I give you an undirected graph and three pens of three different colors and then I ask you to color every vertex with one color such that no adjacent vertex have the same color. Then the only way to solve that is more or less brute-force. ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring), [Advanced stuff](https://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~igor/COMP309/3CP.pdf))

This is a very informal answer I know, but so is the question.

Comment: I have not given a detailed description of my puzzle because I do not want proposed answers to it.

Comment: - just to know if it can be solved by a program

Comment: @Rich: You'll have to say a bit more about it than you have.

Comment: @Brian Tung: Given the information available to the solver (as described) and that all actions / sequence of actions applied to the puzzle in a given state will always result in the same new state, **can it be determined if a program can be written to solve the puzzle?**   Compare to Rubik's cube: after playing with it for 30 seconds, you know how it works - but can you write a program to solve it using only the knowledge of actions and results?

Comment: @Rich: Solve it?  Yes.  Solve it without brute force?  Then I'd say there is insufficient detail to provide an answer.

Comment: @Brian Tung. Thankyou for your help so far. What additional information would be needed to determine solvability?
In addition to the Givens above, the solver knows:

- there are N pieces                       (from state of the puzzle)
- each piece has a location            (from state of the puzzle)
- each piece has a rotation (0 .. R)   (from state of the puzzle)
- there are A actions available to the solver (from Given 3)
- for each 'a' in A the pieces altered by 'a' and those unchanged (from state of the puzzle)

Comment: Backtracking sudoku solvers run in a few ms as well.